# Maven child module in parent pom as dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to create a maven spring-boot project with multiple modules. I have created a parent module with packaging type **pom** and many children submodules with packaging type **jar**.

So my parent's **pom.xml** looks like:

```
<groupId>Creator</groupId>
    <artifactId>DPAI</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>starter</module>
        <module>DatabaseApi</module>
        ...
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

One of submodules: starter contains only starting class annotated with @SpringBootApplicatoion and in its pom.xml there is a  section with other child artifacts like:

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>DPAI</artifactId>        
        <groupId>Creator</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

<artifactId>starter</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Creator</groupId>
            <artifactId>DatabaseApi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
...
    </dependencies>
```

So I'm trying to do some refactoring and move Main.class and all dependencies to my parent's pom, but it doesn't compile with error with message that my dependencies referencing itself.

In my opinion, the problem is that my parent pom contains  section with it's own submodules. Parent of that submoduls is the same pom, where I try to add described dependencies

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
  
  The project Creator:DatabaseApi:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\Workspaces\Creator\DatabaseApi\pom.xml) has 1 error
    'dependencies.dependency. Creator:DatabaseApi:1.0-SNAPSHOT' for Creator:DatabaseApi:1.0-SNAPSHOT is referencing itself. @ Creator:DPAI:1.0-SNAPSHOT, D:\Creator\DPAI\pom.xml, line 29, column 21

Comment: What does your application do? Does it provide any REST webservices? Or some web front-end?

Comment: Rest webservices, doing some statistic calculation - different scenarios provided in different submodules (purpose to used that maths models also in other application).

Saving their results in DB, also fetching some parameters from DB.

Answer (score 2):

The parent.pom can't contain any java code, only Maven specifics e.g. See: https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/#parent-content

Maybe tell us, what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want to remove starter module - it's only dependencies collector and run application, so I'm trying to add java code to my parent module.

What's more, when I just created @SpringBootApplication class in my parent module the application starts, but spring context doesn't see any beans from other modules

Comment: So why do you want a multi-module project at all? What's in the DatabaseApi ? And where is the rest of your business logic?

Comment: Rest of business logic is in other modules - just skipped when I pasted it here.

DatabaseAPI is a module for database communication, it's in seperate module enable importing that jar also for other application.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Parent modules cannot contain Java code.

Answer (score 0):

In a Maven multi module project you usually have a parent Pom (with packaging Pom) and several modules at **the same level** as you already set your project up.
Build the modules without dependecies on your code first, the the dependent modules: In your parent Pom change the order of the modules to

```
<modules>
    <module>DatabaseApi</module>
    <module>starter</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

Comment: No, the point is that, I would like to remove <module>starter</module>, because it contains only Main.class and <dependencies> section for other modules. I'm trying to move that Main.class and <dependencies> section to my parent pom.

Comment: This is not how Maven works. Each Maven project produces one artefact. To build your starter and define its dependencies, you need a Pom for a jar. To build the whole project you need a parent Pom with packaging Pom that produces a description of how to build everything (the Pom itself).

Comment: That's right, so I'm trying to remove one of submodules - starter and move it to parent module.

What's more, when I just created @SpringBootApplication class in my parent module the application starts, but spring context doesn't see any beans from other modules

Comment: You should rethink your architecture ... I would say you have one main application, which is executable and then other modules, which provide library-style-code as dependency.

Comment: In deed, and I'm just trying to move @SpringBootApplication class to my parent - pompacking module.
Now, I suppose that it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm trying to do some refactoring and move Main.class and all
>   dependencies to my parent's pom,

I'm not 100% sure if Maven would support something like the following in the parent POM itself:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>DatabaseApi</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

But for sure it won't support Java classes in a Module with pom-packaging (such as parent modules or multi-module modules). The compiler:compile goal etc. are [not bound to any phase for pom-packaging by default](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings). In other words: Maven does not compile Java classes for pom-modules by default.

My recommendation:
Keep the SpringBootApplication in a Java-based module. For Spring MVC/ WebFlux application I usually create a "-web" module with:

- SpringBootApplication
- web service controllers
- http/ web filters
- global configs such as: security, swagger, async
- application.yml
- ...

It's also the module where I configure the Spring Boot Plugin to create an executable JAR.

Comment: "I'm not 100% sure if Maven would support something like the following in the parent POM itself"

It doesn't work. Could I just put @SpringBootApplication class in parent module like in singe module application?

Comment: @Gajek: As I said: No code in POM projects. Maybe you could bind some Maven goals manually, but it's really not recommended.

Comment: When I just created @SpringBootApplication class in my parent module the application starts, but spring context doesn't see any beans from other modules.

What about single module application, there are java files in pom packing module?

Comment: @Gajek: Did you check the link I've provided? The compiler:compile goal etc. are not bound to any phase for pom-packaging by default. In other words: Maven does not compile Java classes for pom-modules by default.

Comment: @Gajek in single Java module applications you don't use the pom-packaging, but jar/war/ear/ejb/bundle or some other Java based packaging.

Comment: ok, you are right, I have to spend more time on learing maven. The last question, why application starts, when I created @SpringBootApplication class in pom-packing module?

Comment: @Gajek How do you start it? Do you use the Spring Boot Maven Plugin? How is it configured? Please update your question with this information, if this is relevant.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but I don't have any idea, how IntelliJ works internally and which commands are executed. On Dev enviroment I start it on localhost, it's enough to open Main.java file with public static void main and clik on green arrow.
It starts my application on localhost.
Target class files are created.

Comment: @Gajek So you started it from within IntelliJ? Thats an important information. IntelliJ has an own build and run system, AFAIK, which does not always rely on Maven. Thus it might work in IntelliJ but not in Maven.

Comment: Yea, from IntelliJ, but I suppose that it use maven internally.
Important information, I use Community verion of IntelliJ, which doesn't support Spring application, so to run Spring application you have to import it as a Maven project or add maven to existing one. In other ways it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm trying to do some refactoring and move Main.class and all
>   dependencies to my parent's pom

I dont think this is possible. Your parent pom is actually of type pom, meaning you're not actually supposed to have any java code in it. Its meant to hold the versions of jars used in your child modules. You can relate this to the spring-boot-parent module. When we declare the spring-boot-parent module in a spring boot project, your adding your project as a child of the spring-boot-parent. And the parent will manage the versions of all of your dependencies.

I think the best way forward would be to maintain all your service related code in your spring-boot module. Filters, controllers,etc. The other stuff like your jdbc, integration layers can be maintained in other child modules and then referred to the spring module as jar references similar to your example.